# How to formulate an xpath expression to check if checkbox is checked?

Tags: html, xpath, removing-whitespace

I'm new with xpath and trying to formulate an xpath expression that will check if a checkbox is checked.

here's my html,

```html
<label><input type='checkbox' name='name[]' class="some-class-name" /> Text 1</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' name='name[]' class="some-class-name" checked /> Text 2</label>
```

and i have this xpath expression but im not getting any result,

```
//*[contains(text()[normalize-space()], " Text 1 ")] //input[@type="checked" and not(@checked)]
```

How will test if "Text 1" checkbox is checked using xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath expression should select what you want:

```
//*[@type="checkbox" and not(@checked)][contains(normalize-space(following-sibling::text()[position()="1"]), "Text 1")]
```

That returns this element:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id" name="name[]" />
```

Notes:

- The `following-sibling::text()[position()='1']` part is the most significant part here; it means, *The **first** following sibling that is a **text node**.*
- Use the form `contains(normalize-space(…), "Text 1")` to check the value of the text node. Notice especially the `"Text 1"`—you don’t want to use the `contains(normalize-space(…), " Text 1 ")` form that you had in the original, because it will fail due to the spaces in `" Text 1 "`. When you use `normalize-space(…)`, you’re asking for those leading+trailing spaces to be removed from the text node. So you need to check for a match against what the text node will look like with those spaces removed, which is `"Text 1"`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. its working perfectly for this 2 checkboxes. I tried to add more of those line, like

<label><input type='checkbox' name='name[]' class="some-class-name" /> Text 3</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' name='name[]' class="some-class-name" checked /> Text 4</label>

and get the 5th checkbox, but im not getting any result. here's the adjustment I made with the xpath you made

//*[@type="checkbox" and not(@checked)][contains(normalize-space(following-sibling::text()[position()="3"]), "Text 3")]

am i doing this correctly?

Comment: @JohnDiegor It’s very hard to read code pasted into comments here. I’d suggest you post a new question as a follow up to this one, and then post a link to it here. That will get you more visibility for the question, and others on StackOverflow can see it and maybe respond. But I will as well if I have time and somebody else hasn’t already given you a good answer after you’ve posted it and by the time I see it.

Comment: yeah, i noticed its a bit hard to read the HTML codes that i posted in here. but i think i already figured it out @sideshowbarker :-)

Comment: @John awesome, goot to hear